# Does Cordova can work without safari ? (user can't run safari on educational device/ipad)

Tags: cordova, safari

does apps build with Cordova work on IOS devices which hasn't Safari enable/install (ie iPad as educational device, users cant run Safari)

Best regards,
A newbie.

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! Please ask your question in the question and not in the body.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the advice, its done :-)

Comment: Beautiful! This will make it much easier for others to find the question if they have the same problem. Now when I google "Does Cordova work without safari" guess who's question is at the top?

Comment: doh! unbelievable !! I hope having an answer, otherwise visitors coming from google will be disappointed ^^

Comment: I can un-delete my answer below. But It's not a definite answer. Basically, the only way to know is to test it and find out. I didn't see Safari as a dependency to Cordova. And Since cordova is cross-platform, I think it's safe to say that it will work. (I'll un-delete my answer. Hope it doesn't get down-voted for being speculatory)

Answer (score 0):

On IOS (as of IOS8), Cordova uses the [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) JavaScript Engine which is based on Safari [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662994/what-js-engine-does-cordova-use)

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview),

> A WKWebView object displays interactive web content, such as for an
>   in-app browser. You can use the WKWebView class to embed web content
>   in your app.

This leads me to believe that the answer is no. You do not need Safari for the app to work because the app is actually rendering the content itself using a built-in library. That is to say, the app has it's own built in "browser".

**DISCLAIMER:** I have no experience with Cordova and can only spectate based on the available documentation. I recommend you build a very simple Cordova app that displays web content, and test it on the device in question. Or better yet, just use the device, install an app that you know depends on Cordova, and try to run it! :)

Comment: Hello, thank for your reply, that make sense, ill be back to you as soon as i have any confirmation.